# How to change default values in inherited control yet allow to reset their values with instance's designer?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

Consider following scenario:

1. Create new custom control inherited from `DataGridView` named `MyDataGridView`.
2. Open `MyDataGridView` in designer.
3. Change `AllowUserToAddRows` property of `MyDataGridView` custom control to `false`.
4. Use `MyDataGridView` instance in form.
5. Change `AllowUserToAddRows` property of the `MyDataGridView` instance to `true`.

What I expect would happen: my instance should allow user to add rows. It doesn't. The moment I run build, the property of the instance is reset to the value set in `MyDataGridView` definition.

So I'm obviously doing it wrong. How to do it right?

I want `MyDataGridView` to have a different set of default values for properties than standard `DataGridView`, but yet those properties should remain editable in application's designer. What is the most straightforward mean to achieve this?

[Example](http://nisza.org/so/WindowsFormsApplication2.zip)

Comment: I tried to create new, copied properties in `MyDataGridView` code with default values set. They work with `Reset` designer option, but still building the project makes my instance have all properties reset to the exact values from `MyDataGridView` designer - not its instance's.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's one way of doing this, but it's terrible! I'm still looking for an easier way:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test {
    public partial class MyDataGridView : DataGridView {

        bool _AllowUserToAddRows;
        [Category("Behavior")]
        [Description("Value indicating whether the option to add rows is displayed to the user")]
        [DefaultValue(false)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
        public new bool AllowUserToAddRows {
            get { return _AllowUserToAddRows; }
            set { base.AllowUserToAddRows = _AllowUserToAddRows = value; } }

    }
}
```